# Unpacking double values from binary file

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, binary, floating-point

I understand that there are issues reading C double values in Python. In my program, I am reading from a binary file and convert numeric values to integers of various sizes without an problems. I use the code below to read the double values.

```
peakDescriptor["area"] = struct.unpack("d",file.read(8))
```

There is a massive discrepancy between what the values should be and what I get. The first table below is what I get:
methane                 3.6368230562528605e-307
ethane                      -8.243249632731949e+306
propane                     1.839329701286865e-60
2-methylpropane             -2.55127317345224e-306
butane                      3.737451552798833e+59
...

And this table shows, what the values should be:
methane                     97.25
ethane                      426.50
propane                     2755.60
2-methylpropane             3390.25
butane                      10906.60
...

How can I correctly read these numbers?

My code can be [found here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/te0kymlhwl4x89y/readtcfiles.py?dl=0)

The raw and result files are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnds8g6in1mc5v5/nap%20ex%203-1%200800%208-9-17_004.raw?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pbmj82kryu1jq9e/nap%20ex%203-1%200800%208-9-17_004.rst?dl=0)

Please let me know if you have problems accessing the files!

P.S. I have tried changing the formatting string to include a ">" sign as per the struct documentation - this still results in unexpected values, as well as a number of NaN's!

Comment: [Can't you provide a toy data set and your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so people can reproduce and identify your problem? Imho at the moment, there is not sufficient information to address this problem.

Comment: I have just added links for the source code file and the datafiles. Thank you.

Comment: @HillInHarwich: It would be much better if you posted the relevant byte sequences directly in the question. I can see the DropBox files, but they're large and I have no idea which part of them you're trying to interpret.

Comment: "I understand that there are issues reading C double values in Python." <- I'd be interested to know where you gained such an understanding, and what the issues are. Python *uses* C doubles under the hood for its floats. I've never encountered any issues working with C double data in Python.

Comment: The issues I read about were only to do with reading more decimal places than were recorded by c/c++ programs. A very minor problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: you need to interpret your bytes using the correct byte order. It turns out that in this case, the correct byte order is neither little-endian (order `01234567`) nor big-endian (`76543210`), but the order `32107654`, so you need a tiny bit of preprocessing before you can use the `struct` module. See the function `interpret_float` below.

In more detail: looking first at the methane value, and making the (fairly safe) guess that the machine you're using is little endian, the bytes that you read in from the file look like this:

```
>>> field = struct.pack('<d', 3.6368230562528605e-307)
>>> field
b'\x00\x00\x003@XP\x00'
```

As you've already discovered, trying to interpret these bytes directly as an IEEE 754 binary64 (i.e., double precision) floating-point value assuming either little-endian or big-endian byte order doesn't produce plausible values:

```
>>> struct.unpack('<d', field)[0]
3.6368230562528605e-307
>>> struct.unpack('>d', field)[0]
1.08755143765e-312
```

However, there's a suspicious similarity between the bytes of `field` and the bytes of the expected value of `97.25`. It's slightly easier to see if you expand the bytes out to see their integer values:

```
>>> list(struct.pack('<d', 97.25))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 88, 64]
>>> list(field)
[0, 0, 0, 51, 64, 88, 80, 0]
```

Not a perfect match, but the `0, 80, 88, 64` sequence in the bytes for `97.25` looks suspiciously like the exact reversal of the sequence `64, 88, 80, 0` in the second. Besides little-endian and big-endian, there's another pair of byte orders for IEEE 754 double-precision floats that turn up occasionally (usually on ARM hardware), and that's word-swapped little-endian, or word-swapped big-endian (both of which are sometimes referred to as mixed-endian or middle-endian). In your case, it looks as though the bytes you have are in order `32107654`, where `7` denotes the most significant byte (the one containing the sign bit and the most significant 7 bits of the biased exponent), and `0` the least significant byte (containing the 8 least significant bits of the fraction). So if we swap the two words, we should be able to interpret as regular big-endian:

```
>>> def interpret_float(x):
...     return struct.unpack('>d', x[4:] + x[:4])
... 
>>> interpret_float(field)
(97.25000000000072,)
```

That looks much more promising! Let's try the same on the next couple of values. You didn't give the original bytes for these, so again I need to reverse-engineer them from the bad values you gave.

```
>>> ethane_field = struct.pack('<d', -8.243249632731949e+306)
>>> interpret_float(ethane_field)
(426.4999999999999,)
>>> propane_field = struct.pack('<d', 1.839329701286865e-60)
>>> interpret_float(propane_field)
(2755.600000000001,)
```

From these, it looks as though our guess about a byte order of `32107654` was correct.

If my original guess was wrong and you are in fact on a big-endian machine, or you're on a little-endian machine and the values you show were obtained by doing a `struct.unpack('>d', ...)` rather than a plain old `struct.unpack('d', ...)`, then the byte order is `45670123`, and you'll need to replace the `'>d'` format in `interpret_float` with `'<d'` instead.

You can find out what byte order your host machine is using by looking at `sys.byteorder` in Python. On my machine, and on any other x86-64-based machine, it gives `'little'`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.byteorder
'little'
```

Comment: Perfect!!! This worked. Thank you so much! Just out of curiosity - why would doubles be encoded in this way?!

Comment: @HillInHarwich: No idea. :-) Are the values coming from some form of embedded hardware at any point?

Comment: No they don’t - all the results and areas are calculated from raw data (which can be read as integers without a problem)